# Inicializar um formulario com valores de um objeto com ANGULAR 4

Tags: typescript, angular

Estou com dificuldade em criar um CRUD com Angular 4. Estou tentando criar um formulário colocando o valor de um objeto nele, para conseguir edita-lo.

Segue exemplo:

```
<form #editar="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="lerClientes()">
  <div>
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome"   name="nome"  (ng-model)="cliente.nome"/>
    <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome:</label>
    <input type="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" (ng-model)="cliente.sobrenome"/>
  </div> 
<div>
  <button type="submit"> botao</button>
  </div>>
</form>
```

Comment: Você poderia [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/295461/edit) sua pergunta e adicionar a estrutura do objeto ?

Comment: Davidson você poderia postar o typescript do seu componente?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, para você conseguir editar os valores pelo Typescript precisa alterar o 
`(ng-model)="cliente.nome"` para `[(ng-model)]="cliente.nome"`, pois a propriedade entre os [] é apenas um GET para poder setar precisa dos (), assim você vai utilizar o two-way bind, se quiser utilize para os outros inputs que você queira alterar para pegar o valor no typescript, esqueci de falar, para aparecer direto no formulário, é necessário que coloque no typescript.
Por exemplo no contrutor coloque:

```
cliente.nome = "Rogério";
cliente.sobrenome = "Almeira";
```

E com o [(ng-model)] no HTML assim que for alterado o valor já vai ser salvo na variável.

Answer (score -1):

```
export class AppCtorComponent {
  title: string;
  myHero: string;

  constructor() {
    this.title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    this.myHero = 'Windstorm';
  }
}
```